# celery - subtasks sort inside a group

Tags: python, celery

I'm using celery for parallelize some long running jobs.
Actually my chunking algo cannot guarantee same work for each 
subtasks. So i've noticed this unexpected behavior using 
unbalanced tasks inside a group.

the example task:

```
@app.task(name='step')
def step(s):
   print 'step received:', s
   time.sleep(s)
   return s
```

In this scenario :

```
%time group(step.s(10), step.s(1), step.s(1), step.s(3))
CPU times: user 32.2 ms, sys: 33.6 ms, total: 65.8 ms
Wall time: <b>13.6 s</b>
Out[5]: [10, 1, 1, 3]
```

I think that no combination of 1,1,3,10 cannot exceed 10sec (plus a small time for tasks).

I've noticed that this call:

- step(10)  -> worker 1
- step(1)   -> worker 2
- step(1)   -> worker 3

after that, worker 2 and 3 are busy for short time(only 1 sec), so they could work on last task, but "step(3)" will be handled ONLY after "step(10)" was finished.

It sounds strange to me. 
Any suggestion?

Thank you
Gla

Comment: It seems related to prefork: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/optimizing.html#prefork-pool-prefetch-settings. Is this the right way?

Comment: well... does using `-Ofair` make a difference?

Comment: Yes it does. Now it seem to work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is because of celery's default [prefork](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/optimizing.html#prefork-pool-prefetch-settings) behavior. You can override this and get the behavior you want by using the `-Ofair` flag when running the workers.